# Mongo DB - unable to retrieve object stored in type:Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm fairly new to MongoDB and have started to learn about relationships. I'm running into an issue where i'm trying to store an array of objects into one of my collection models. Basically the array is storing fine in the sense that if I look at it in compass all the correct information is there. The issue lies with retrieving the array, here is looks like the object in my array has been flattened to a string as it's just retrieving somthing like this:

Note: i'm using node Express as my BE framework

```
members: [ [Object] ] } ]
```

Here is my model below:

```
const teamSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        trim:true,
        required:'Please enter a team name'
    },
    owner:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref:'User'
  },
    members:{
        type:Array,
  }  
});
```

And here is how I use the model in Node:

```
const team = new Team({
        name:req.body.teamName,
  owner:req.user._id,
  members:[{
    id:req.user._id,
    privilege:'admin'
  }]
})

  try {
    await team.save();
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
```

Here is what it looks like stored in MongoDB Compass
[image]

But when retrieving it and trying to modify it like so:

```
const team = await Team.find({'_id':teamId});
```

finds it no problem but the members array just displays as what I mentioned before:

```
members: [ [Object] ] } ]
```

can anyone tell me where I might be going wrong? Think it might be to do with the way i'm saving it rather than retrieving it

Comment: How are you "displaying" the members array to see `members: [ [Object] ] } ]`?

Comment: If you try `members[0].privilege` do you see `admin`? Looks to me like your just spitting out the result to stdout? Try `util.inspect(team)`. You will need to require `util`.

Comment: is I console log board.members[0].privilege then I get undefined. That is also how i'm 'displaying' it.

Comment: Yeh so you're "displaying" it using console.log, which is wrong. You should never use `console.log()` in the Node process. You can Google why. But for your particular case, it will only ever show you `[Object]` unless you use a tool like util which will convert your Object into a readable output. And where has `board` come from??

Comment: Think that's the first time i've heard I shouldn't use console log in the node process.... Utill also returns undefined.  Also please excuse the board, this should be team

Comment: Then you've been speaking to the wrong people Ben! Here's a good starting point for beginners: https://webapplog.com/seven-things-you-should-stop-doing-with-node-js/

Comment: Great, well good to know about util.inspect. Looks like the issue stands regardless of how I try to display the object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162588/discussion-between-adamjeffers-and-ben-liger).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use the `projection` field of the `find`to return the array in the searched element:

```
const team = await Team.find({'_id':teamId}, {'members': 1});
```

Comment: Hi Jack, no sucess i'm afraid. Still returned me the same thing. Think it might be down to the way i'm saving it

Comment: Add console.log(JSON.stringify(team))

Comment: I think that the problem relies in the fact 'team' is a const. You can try to define a variable and set it to '[]'. Then you can push the array inside.

Comment: hmmm interesting, the object and it's details are in there if I stringify it! I tried changing team to var team = ... and ir still gives me the same issue

Comment: Try var abc = []; and then abc.push(team);

Comment: still doesn't show me the nested object in the array!